# How to implement armor?

Tags: mathematics, python

I am a newbie in Python, I am very bad at math too and I need some help. Also close/move this post if you feel this isn't the right place for it.

```
Hero1 = 5000   # His HP is 5k.
Hero1dmg = 200 # damage output
```

How can I subtract some value (let's say 20%) from Hero1's damage output?

Comment: yes, i'm extremely bad at basic maths and has been one of the reasons I didn't start to learn programming until last week. thanks for the link

Comment: Math is used extensively in programming and even more in game programming. You'll want to make sure you have a good understanding of the basics before continuing, otherwise you'll run into a lot of problems. Good luck!

Comment: I understand the risks of not having a good knowledge of basic maths but I just love gaming/programming and it's the only motivation I have to learn math since I hate math. :)

Comment: Are we seriously teaching percentage math now?

Comment: Why do people have trouble understanding that someone can be bad at math? Why so ignorant? Please, stay on topic, if you can help me, thanks but if not, please do not post here. Thank you!

Comment: @user The comments are for commenting; the answers for answering. Everybody's doing it right so far. :)

Comment: @Anko, yeah sure but why would someone waste their time to demotivate or just post a cynical/negative comment on someone's question? Seems very ignorant to me... It's not like I deny that I'm not good at math. I am bad at math, get over it. Thanks.

Comment: It's not that they're mad at you, they're debating whether or not this is the place to answer those kinds of questions.

Comment: Well someone edited my original question. I CLEARLY stated that if this is the wrong place for this question, feel free to move or close it. If a mod comes and says this isn't the place to answer these kind of questions, it would be fine for them to close/move it. But I don't know who edited my comment and deleted that part.

Comment: There, I edited it again for clarification.

Comment: It's OK to be bad at math. I think @jh wants to say that this is a *game development site*, not a *math site* and that most of this question is math. It's nothing personal - we're just trying to keep the site well organised.

Comment: @Anko I appreciate that, I really do, but instead of killing my hopes of ever being a programmer, he could have just said that he doesn't think this is the right place for that kind of question. Cheers

Comment: @user27102 Don't worry about it being closed, it was basic enough that it wasn't too likely that people would come here searching for that answer. It doesn't mean it was a bad question, this just wasn't the best place for it. Do continue to ask questions here :)

Comment: I can see how you took my comment as directed toward you, since I didn't really specify what I was talking about. However by "we" I was addressing the anonymous collective that is the audience of this site, and I was commenting about the fact that multiple people upvoted this question, signaling that they think this is a good question for this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very basic formula would be:

```
damageAfterArmorCalc = damageAmt*(1-armorReductionPercent)
```

`damageAmt` Is the original amount of damage to be done.

`armorReductionPercent` is the percent of damage the armor negates, this percentage should be a value from 0 to 1, so the 20% in your example would be `.2`. If we're doing 100 damage initially, we can look at some examples for what that does.

So what's happening here, if the armor does not negate any damage, then we get:

`100 * (1 - 0) = 100*1 = 100`

As you know, any number multiplied by one is still that number. Now if the armor negates 100% of damage, we would get

`100 * (1 - 1) = 100*0 = 0`

Since any number multiplied by zero is zero. Now we know it works for both extremes, how about the inbetween values? Say it negates 20% of damage as in your example. , we can see how that looks:

`100 * (1 - .2) = 100*.8 = 80`

We know that 20% of 100 is 20, and that 100 minus 20 is 80. So it looks like this works just fine.

I suggest you look into some basic math tutorials and get the basics down. [Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) is a great resource for this.

Answer (score 1):

To subtract 20% off his damage output, multiply by .8 (20% = 0.2, so multiply by 1 - .2 = 0.8).  That makes the new damage 160.